# General Questions: Azure Virtual Machine Scale Sets

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

I am learning VMSS and have two general questions for my understanding.

Q1 : **How new virtual machines gets provisioned in the VMSS?**

- Does it clone the existing VM from VMSS or use Image every time to provision a new VM?

. If it clone existing VM from VMSS then which VM out of the existing VM’s it clone?

. If it provision new VM from the image then in the case of platform image, do I need to install web server and other changes every time because I do not have a requirement to use a custom image?

2. How to make changes to the VM’s in VMSS?

. If I need to modify web server settings then how do I make the same settings on the other VM’s in VMSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1: How new virtual machines get provisioned in the VMSS?**

It creates the new VM from the configuration that you set for the VMSS every time, not clone the existing VMs. If you do not use the custom image, then you need to install web server and other changes every time for the new VMs.

**Q2: How to make changes to the VM’s in VMSS?**

You can use the VM extension to make the changes to the VMs in the VMSS. Or just use the custom image.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are suggesting, every time new VM gets created in the scale set it gets created from the Image?

Comment: @James Yes, the new VM is created from the image that you configured for the VMSS.